# Batch file find connected Citrix server

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, citrix

I would like to create a diagnostic batch file that will output what Citrix server and application a users is connected to.

Currently I have to open Citrix connection center to find this information.  But I would like to record this server and application information so I can use it for problem tracking.

Is there any way to interface with Citrix on the client side with dos or powershell to output this information?

[image: example]

Comment: [This](https://www.citrix.com/blogs/2017/12/01/scripting-citrix-xenserver-with-powershell-and-command-line/) might point you in the right direction to get started.

Comment: I looked at this, but the toolkit seems to be geared to the server side. :(  I am looking for something on the client side.

Comment: Which Citrix client and version are you using?

Comment: Clients are version 4.7

Comment: Do certain client versions have this ability?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to find a command line arguments that would but did not find anything that would work.

I was able to find simple work around, I found this command line tool that takes screenshots.  Although not the best solution, the script will open connection manager and waits 3 seconds and then takes a screenshot.  Citrix really needs to add command line for support.

https://github.com/chuntaro/screenshot-cmd

start "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Citrix\ICA Client\concentr.exe" & ping 127.0.0.1 -n 3 > nul & \server\screenshot-cmd.exe -wt "Citrix Connection Center" -o \server\TEMP\citrixshot.png & taskkill /IM concentr.exe >nul